# how to remove part of a string (not just replace it) via regex ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, regex, gsub

I have a string from a api response that I use a after_filter to adjust the body of the message. I am replacing a few characters and removing a whole node.

```
response.body = response.body.gsub(/\<(test.*)\>/, '<\1 "random_stuff">').gsub(
      /\<(wantToDelete.*)\>/, "").gsub(/\<\/(wantToDelete.*)\>/, "")
```

This somewhat works. Except as expected the part that I want to delete is now a blank string when a really just want it gone.

Before:

```
<random_stuff>
  <wantToDelete>
    <startDate>2013-11-15</startDate>
  </wantToDelete>
</random_stuff>
```

After:

```
<testrandom_stuff>

  <startDate>2013-11-15</startDate>

</testrandom_stuff>
```

What I want:

```
 <testrandom_stuff>
  <startDate>2013-11-15</startDate>
 </testrandom_stuff>
```

Any way to remove the node and gaps?

Comment: Replace them with an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line break is usually just the character `\n` Maybe you could try to match it in the regexp aswell?

```
response.body.gsub(/\<(test.*)\>/, '<\1 "random_stuff">').gsub(
  /\<(wantToDelete.*)\>\n/, "").gsub(/\<\/(wantToDelete.*)\>\n/, "")
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you very much... sad I didn't realize that myself

Answer (score 0):

While it's possible to manipulate XML using `gsub` and regular expressions, it's not recommended because it results in a very fragile solution. XML and HTML are very difficult to process due to the beginning and ending tags, and their freeform nature being prone to changing.

Instead use a parser, like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org):

```
require 'nokogiri'

str = <<EOT
<random_stuff>
  <wantToDelete>
    <startDate>2013-11-15</startDate>
  </wantToDelete>
</random_stuff>
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(str)
```

At this point the XML is converted to a DOM in memory and can be searched and changed quite easily.

This is how to find the `<random_stuff>` and `<startDate>` tags:

```
random_stuff = doc.at('random_stuff')
start_date = doc.at('startDate')
```

Once we have those, we can tell Nokogiri to replace the child nodes of `<random_stuff>` with the `<startDate>` node, and rename the `<random_stuff>` node to `<testrandom_stuff>`:

```
random_stuff.children = start_date
random_stuff.name = 'test' + random_stuff.name
```

Notice that Nokogiri automatically adjusted the name of the closing tag too.

And here's what it looks like:

```
puts doc.to_xml
# >> <testrandom_stuff>
# >>   <startDate>2013-11-15</startDate>
# >> </testrandom_stuff>
```